# How to handle HTML form in JavaFX application

Tags: webview, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

Can some one please help to how can I capture onclick event of HTML button inside JavaFX?
    onClick of that button javascript alert should display, I can display HTML page on applet window but onclick event is not working

**HTML:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>WebView</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="help.css">
    <script>
        function buttonClick() {
            alert("Button Clicked");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="buttonClick()">Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Bellow is my JavaFX code:

```
public class WebViewSample extends Application {

    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create scene
        stage.setTitle("WebView");
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(), 750, 500, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // apply CSS style
        //scene.getStylesheets().add("webviewsample/BrowserToolbar.css");        
        // show stage
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```java
class Browser extends Region {

    private HBox toolBar;
    private static String[] imageFiles = new String[]{
        "help.png"
    };
    private static String[] captions = new String[]{
        "Help"
    };
    private static String[] urls = new String[]{
        WebViewSample.class.getResource("help.html").toExternalForm()
    };    

    final Hyperlink[] hpls = new Hyperlink[captions.length];
    final Image[] images = new Image[imageFiles.length];
    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();        
    final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();   

    public Browser() {
        //apply the styles
        getStyleClass().add("browser");

        for (int i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {
            // create hyperlinks
            Hyperlink hpl = hpls[i] = new Hyperlink(captions[i]);
            Image image = images[i] =
                    new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageFiles[i]));
            hpl.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
            final String url = urls[i];

            hpl.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {                  
                    webEngine.executeScript("url");
                }
            });


        }

        comboBox.setPrefWidth(60);

        // create the toolbar
        toolBar = new HBox();
        toolBar.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        toolBar.getStyleClass().add("browser-toolbar");
        toolBar.getChildren().add(comboBox);
        toolBar.getChildren().addAll(hpls);
        toolBar.getChildren().add(createSpacer());

        //add components
        getChildren().add(toolBar);
        getChildren().add(browser);
    }    

    private Node createSpacer() {
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return spacer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        double tbHeight = toolBar.prefHeight(w);
        layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h-tbHeight,0,HPos.CENTER,VPos.CENTER);
        layoutInArea(toolBar,0,h-tbHeight,w,tbHeight,0,HPos.CENTER,VPos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return 750;
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return 600;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you are not seeing anything is that you have not defined an `onAlert` handler for the `webEngine`. Try the simplest thing:

```
    // in the constructor of `Browser`
    webEngine.setOnAlert((WebEvent<String> event) -> {
        System.out.println("ALERT!!!! " + event.getData());
    });
```

This will be printing the alert in the std out. This also means that the event is actually captured.

If you want to call Java code from this event, you will have to read [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx) **(EDIT 2017/08/06: the link is gone now; [this](http://mws-mdm.blogspot.gr/2016/05/communicating-between-javascript-and.html) is the closest I could find)**. In short:

1. Make an object containing the code you want to call, e.g.:

   ```
   public class Bridge {
       public void doSomething() {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Place it in the page context:

   ```
   JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
   jsobj.setMember("bridge", new Bridge());
   ```
3. Call it from the JS event handler:

   ```
   function buttonClick() {
       bridge.doSomething();
   }
   ```
4. Use `JSObject.removeMember()` once you no longer need the bridge to remove it
5. Pay attention to security!

Comment: Hi Nikos, I have one more doubt, If I have 2 button with 2 different JavaScript functions, how can I differentiate those?

<button onclick="buttonClick1()">Click</button>
<button onclick="buttonClick2()">Click</button>

 <script>
            function buttonClick1() {
                alert("first button clicked");
                //bridge.doSomething();
            }
            
            function buttonClick2() {
                alert("second button clicked");
                //bridge.doSomething();
            }
        </script>

Comment: The same principle; e.g. make another object, `Bridge2`, -OR- make a new method `doSomethingElse()` in `Bridge` etc...

Comment: Thanks Nikos.
1. Could you please tell me how to retrieve form fields if I have a textbox like
 <input type="text" id="text-box">

Comment: 2. How to navigate from one page to another with content please? this could solve all my doubts.

Comment: For (1) you need standard Javascript manipulation - if not sure its better to ask another question. (2) is yet another question too, you should provide more details on what exactly you want. Standard HTML links work in many cases...

Comment: Thanks Nikos. Sure will ask another question

Comment: Great answer, but the `this` link above is now broken - do you have an updated link?

Comment: @DrAl Ach, web content comes and goes... and I couldn't find the same entry in Oracle's blog. [This](http://mws-mdm.blogspot.gr/2016/05/communicating-between-javascript-and.html) is the closest I could find. (At least I followed the wise Stackoverflow advise to include linked content in the answer :) ) Updating above too;